# Is python's eval safer in thick-client desktop app

Tags: python

How dangerous is using eval in an in-house desktop application.  I understand the problem in a web app. is it really a problem in a desktop thick client application.

We have a scenario we we allow users to create queries using an in-house DSL and dynamically compiling into python code using eval

Comment: Danger is relative. Dangerous from a security standpoint, or from a stability standpoint? If you allow arbitrary code, you need probably need to handle all exceptions gracefully at a minimum from a usability perspective.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment said, it depends on what you mean by "safe". From a security standpoint `eval` is the end of all hope; once you have it, there is no going back, the user can do anything he wants.

[Consider](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) for example

```
eval('(lambda fc=(lambda n: [c for c in ().__class__.__bases__[0].__subclasses__() if c.__name__ == n][0]): fc("function")(fc("code")(0,0,0,0,"KABOOM",(), (),(),"","",0,""),{})())()')
```

which will segfault CPython2 (see? no hands!). It could also have overwritten your OS with cat-pictures or solve NP vs. P and turn your PC into a black hole. The point being that once you *may* allow user-supplied input to get into `eval()`, you are in danger. Don't even bother trying to correctly escape user-supplied input.

Comment: It's a desktop application. This limits the scope of potential attacks to the user's computer running the program. What would be the point of trying to hack into or bring down a local application through `eval`? There's nothing that you could do via `eval`, that you couldn't otherwise do to your own computer.